# Browsable(false) at run time?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a datasource to populate my datagridview with the data. However, im trying to find a way for the user to be able to hide columns that he does not want to see.

I am able to hide and show columns before the program runs using:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public string URL
{
    get
    {
        return this._URL;
    }
    set
    {
        this._URL = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChnaged("URL");
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to change the `[Browsable(false)]` at run time.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Basically, I want to bind an "on/off" to a menu.

Apologies if im not using the right terminology when explaining my problem, I am self taught and started a few weeks ago - so still very newbie :)

Edit:

Cant hide the column because when i run my update function all columns appear again. Here is my function for updating:

```
    private void UpdateResults()
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           this.dgvResults.SuspendLayout();
                           this.dgvResults.DataSource = null;
                           this.dgvResults.DataSource = this._mySource;
                           this.dgvResults.ResumeLayout();
                           this.dgvResults.Refresh();
                       }
                       ));
    }
```

Comment: Just as a note, you have a misspelling: `this.RaisePropertyChnaged("URL");`

Comment: Ops! Didn't notice that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At run time, you can just specify the column as being invisible:

```
dgv.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Problem is that when i update the datagridview again the column will appear visible again

Comment: @gwenda how are you updating it that is causing this to happen? update your question with the code that does the update. I believe you may have implmented it incorrectly and that is causing it not to respect `Visible`

Comment: @gwenda I don't think all that Layout and null stuff is necessary.  After you set the DataSource, go through the columns to determine which ones are visible as set by the user.  I'm assuming you have this as a list somewhere.

Comment: Figured it out, i just put visible check inside update function - thanks a lot for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as others had mention the purpose of `BrowsableAttribute` is different, but I understand what you want to do:

Let's suppose that we want to create a UserControl than wraps a `DataGridView` and gives the user the ability to select which columns to display, allowing for complete runtime binding. A simple design would be like this (I'm using a `ToolStrip`, but you can always use a `MenuStrip` if that's what you want):

[image]

```
    private void BindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
        this.countLabel.Text = string.Format("Count={0}", this.bindingSource.Count);
        this.columnsToolStripButton.DropDownItems.Clear();

        this.columnsToolStripButton.DropDownItems.AddRange(
            (from c in this.dataGrid.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
             select new Func<ToolStripMenuItem, ToolStripMenuItem>(
                 i => {
                     i.CheckedChanged += (o1, e2) => this.dataGrid.Columns[i.Text].Visible = i.Checked;
                     return i;
                 })(
                 new ToolStripMenuItem {
                     Checked = true,
                     CheckOnClick = true,
                     Text = c.HeaderText
                 })).ToArray());
    }
```

In this case, `bindingSource` is the intermediary `DataSource` of the `dataGrid` instance, and I'm responding to changes in `bindingSource.ListChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this *properly* at runtime is to provide a custom ITypedList implementation on the collection, or provide a TypeDescriptionProvider for the type, or (for single-object bindings, not lists), to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor. Additionally, you would need to provide your own filtered PropertyDescriptor implementation. Is it really worth it? In most cases: no. It is much easier to configure the grid properly, showing (or not) the appropriate columns by simply choosing which to add.